# Como saber de qual id formulário está sendo enviada uma função?

Tags: jquery

Como posso saber de qual id do formulário está enviada determinada função? A função é `buscar_cidades()` e está presente em 2 formulários `Pessoa Física` e `Pessoa Jurídica`.

Como saber no jQuery de qual formulário(id) está sendo enviada a função?

```
<form action="" id="pessoa_fisica">
    <select name="estado" onchange="buscar_cidades()">
       ...
    </select>
</form>

<form action="" id="pessoa_juridica">
    <select name="estado" onchange="buscar_cidades()">
       ...
    </select>
</form>
```

> **Atualização**

Sabendo de qual id está sendo enviada a função, como capturar o select desse id sabendo-se que o select tem class `estado`?

```
  var formid = $(e).closest("form").attr("id");
  var estado = ??????????
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em JavaScript podes passar `this` na tua função que é chamada no evento `change` para que dentro da mesma possas saber qual o elemento que a usou.

Com jQuery podes depois converter para um objeto, subir ao formulário e recolher o `id`:

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/j2vg8v8w/)

```
function buscar_cidades(e) {
    var formId = $(e).closest("form").attr("id");
    alert(formId);
}
```

Para uma solução apenas em JavaScript, podes:

```
function buscar_cidades(e) {
    var formId = e.form.getAttribute("id");
    alert(formId);
}
```

Comment: Me ajudou perfeitamente, pode só me dar mais um empurrãozinho na parte **Atualização** da pergunta??

Comment: O `select` é o `$(e)` em jQuery quando dentro da função. Se por exemplo queres o valor selecionado: `alert($(e).find('option:selected').val());`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="Formulário" name="Formulário1" method="post" action= "ExercicioPratico4.php">

    <p><b><font size="10px">FICHA DE SÓCIO</font></b></p>
    <p>Nome:
        <label for="nome"></label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" size="25" />
    </p>
    <p>Morada:
        <label for="morada"></label>
        <input type="text" name="morada" id="morada" size="30"/>
        Localidade:
        <label for="localidade"></label>
        <input type="text" name="localidade" id="localidade" size="7"/>
    </p>
    <p>Cód. Postal:
        <label for="postal"></label>
        <input type="text" name="postal" size="2" maxlength="4" id="postal"> - <input type="text" name="cep2" size="2" maxlength="3">
        Data de nascimento:
        <label for="nascimento"></label>
        <input type="text" name="dia" size="1" maxlength="2" value="dd" id="nascimento"> /
        <input type="text" name="mes" size="1" maxlength="2" value="mm" id="nascimento"> /
        <input type="text" name="ano" size="2" maxlength="4" value="aaaa" id="nascimento">
        Nacionalidade:
        <label for="nacionalidade"></label>
        <input type="text" name="nacionalidade" id="nacionalidade" size="15"/>
    </p>
    <p>Tel:
        <label for="tel"></label>
        <input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" size="7" maxlength="9"/>
        Telemóvel:
        <label for="telemovel"></label>
        <input type="text" name="telemovel" id="telemovel" size="7" maxlength="9"/> 
        Email:
        <label for="email"></label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30"/>
    </p>
        <p>Desejo-me inscrever como Sócio, pagando a cota de <input type="checkbox" name="cota">1 Euro <input type="checkbox" name="cota">5 Euros Mensais
        </p>
    <p>Data:
        <label for="data"></label>
        <input type="text" name="dia" size="1" maxlength="2"> /
        <input type="text" name="mes" size="1" maxlength="2"> /
        <input type="text" name="ano" size="2" maxlength="4">
    </p>
            <p>
        <input type="submit" name="Enviar" id="Enviar" value="Enviar" />
        </p>
</form> 






echo "Localidade: $localidade<br>";

$postal = $_POST["postal"];
echo "Cód. Postal: $postal <br>";

$nascimento = $_POST["dia"];
echo "Data de nascimento: $nascimento/";

$nascimento = $_POST["mes"];
echo "$nascimento/";

$nascimento = $_POST["ano"];
echo "$nascimento<br>";

$nacionalidade = $_POST["nacionalidade"];
echo "Nacionalidade: $nacionalidade<br>";

$tel = $_POST["tel"];
echo "Tel: $tel<br>";

$telemovel = $_POST["telemovel"];
echo "Telemóvel: $telemovel<br>";

$email = $_POST["email"];
echo "Email: $email<br>";

$cota = $_POST["cota"];
echo "Cota: $cota<br>";

$data = $_POST["dia"];
echo "Data: $data/";

$data = $_POST["mes"];
echo "$data/";

$data = $_POST["ano"];
echo "$data<br>";
?>
```